# Marshaling c++ strncpy function from dll into c#

Tags: c#, string, dll, char

Below is a toy example to better understand marshaling of string types between c# and c++/dll.

What's the best way to marshal the "MyStrCopy" Function below into c#?
(Preferably without using the unsafe keyword and by marshaling the type into and out of c# as a string type.)

File: MyStrCopy.cs

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MySpace {
    class MyDll {
        [DllImport (@"MyStrCopy")]
        public static extern void MyStrCopy(
            string dest????, string source????, int dest_length????);
    }
}
```

FILE: MyStrCopy.h:

```
extern "C" {
    void __declspec(dllexport) MyStrCopy(
        char* dest, const char* source, int dest_length);
}
```

FILE: MyStrCopy.cpp

```
#include <cstring>
#include "MyStrCopy.h"

void MyStrCopy(char* dest, const char* source, int dest_len) {
    strncpy(dest, source, dest_len);
    dest[dest_len-1] = 0; // zero terminated when source > dest
}
```

I compile the above file "MyStrCopy.cpp" into a dll called: MyStrCopy.dll

I'm also a little bit curious what it would look like if you return char* as well under same preference of not using unsafe and marshaling type to string.  example, if dll exported function looks like this instead:

```
char* MyStrCopy(char* dest, const char* source, int dest_len) {
    return strncpy(dest, source, dest_len);
}
```

Comment: Using a C function that was broken by design is very unwise, strncpy() is fatally flawed since it doesn't guarantee it will zero-terminate the string.  That will crash the C# program with an undiagnosable AccessViolationException.  This toy is going to be another programmer's big headache, voting to close.

Comment: That's a good point, Add the follow after strncpy() and it works in all cases: dest[dest_len-1] = 0;  Anyways, the point is just to see an example of [DllImport] syntax in C# that allows you to pass strings to functions like strncpy() whatever they may be... In My case, I was really trying to pop some values out of a list<string> from c++ side into c# side using DLL interop.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MySpace
{       
    class MyDll {
        [DllImport("MyStrCopy.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern void MyStrCopy(
             StringBuilder  dst_str, 
             string         src_str, 
             int            dst_len);       

        static void ExampleUsage() {
            int           dest_len   = 100;
            StringBuilder dest_str   = new StringBuilder(dest_len);
            string        source     = "this is a string";
            MyStrCopy(dest_str, source, dest_len);
            return;
        }       

    } //class
} //namespace
```